# how to add pdf in phonegap build

Tags: android, pdf, phonegap-build

I want to add a pdf file with my app. but it seems pdf files doesnot work with phonegap build. child browser plugin is an option. but how to use child browser plugin in phonegap build. i aM NEW TO HTML, CSS and phonegap

Comment: How do you want to add the pdf file? Display it? Provide a download link?

Comment: i wanna display it in my app. the app is a textbook app for college students. its like if they click on a subject it displays the pdf..